# How to transform Navigation Bar and Navigation Controller in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing a game in which I am using Landscape mode I have total 4 view.
2 views are properly coming in Landscape mode. But in third view I have UITable and Navigation bar. I can able to rotate table in landscape mode but not able to transform Navigation bar and Navigation controller. Navigation bar and Navigation Controller also have Button on it. It also not get transformed. So can anyone have the solution on this.
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform the nagvigation controller's navigation bar by rotaiong it with 90 degree.
Also you might require to set the navigation bar center and frame for setting the proper width to fit with landscape mode..it worked for me :)
hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 7):

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

    CGRect newBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    self.navigationController.view.bounds = newBounds;
    self.navigationController.view.center = CGPointMake(newBounds.size.height / 2.0, newBounds.size.width / 2.0);

    self.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90));

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    self.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(0));
    self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0);

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: For some context. The real sweet sauce is transforming the navigation controller's view itself.

Answer (score 1):

In UIViewController documentation's Class:

**Handling Rotations**

interfaceOrientation  property
– shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
– rotatingFooterView
– rotatingHeaderView
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

hope this helps you too.

A.